# Stuck between JSON nested object & Callback in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, callback

My application calls the module to parse nested JSON object, to read values of 2 keys.

```
parseData(str, function (error, str) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error - parseData : ", err);
    } else {
        console.log(str);
    }
```

And the parseData module is as follows

```
function parseData(str, callback) {

  function recursiveFunction(obj) {
    var keysArray = Object.keys(obj);

    for (var i = 0; i < keysArray.length; i++) {
      var key = keysArray[i];
      var value = obj[key];

      if (value === Object(value)) {
        parseData(value);
      } else {
        if (key == 'title') {
          title = value;
        }

        if (key == 'extract') {
          var extract = value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
          callback(null, JSON.stringify('{"title":'+ title + ', "text":' + extract));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  recursiveFunction(str);

}
```

But it shows following error

```
/modules/parseData.js:22
               callback(null, JSON.stringify('{"title":'+ title + ',    "text":' + extract));
               ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Why is callback failing ? How to return back JSON object ?

EDIT

There were some errors in the code and now corrected.

```
   function parseData(str, callback) {
       function recursiveFunction(obj) {
           var keysArray = Object.keys(obj);

           for (var i = 0; i < keysArray.length; i++) {
               var key = keysArray[i];
               var value = obj[key];

               if (value === Object(value)) {
                   recursiveFunction(value);
               } else {
                   if (key == 'title') {
                       title = value;
                   }

                   if (key == 'extract') {
                       var extract = value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," "); 
                       callback(null, JSON.stringify('{"title":'+ title + ', "text":' + extract));
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       recursiveFunction(str);
    };
```

Comment: Your first code block is missing a `}` and a `)`; is that a mis-post or does your program have a syntax error?

Comment: add `callback` as a param when you call the function recursively

Comment: `callback(null, JSON.stringify('{"title":'+ title + ', "text":' + extract));` looks very wrong. If you want to create proper JSON you should pass an object to`JSON.stringify`: `callback(null, JSON.stringify({title: title, text: extract}));` . But are you sure you want JSON instead of an object?

Comment: @Jacob, I must some mistake while copying the code

Comment: @FelixKling, we can return back an object, but the API responds back with JSON to the calling request. Is it fine to pass JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `parseData(value);` and not passing a callback; pass `callback` if you want that original callback to be used.

Comment: I did not understand. I am passing callback function to parseData(str, function (error, str)).

Comment: You are calling `parseData` recursively within `parseData`, and that inner call does not pass a callback.

Comment: sorry there was a mistake in my code, I have posted revised code in main question section. Here I am calling recursiveFunction recursively within parseData. So do I need to modify my call for recursiveFunction so the original callback is passed when parseData module is called. 

recursiveFunction(str, callback);

Am I right ?

Comment: The way it's written now, you shouldn't be getting that same error. If you're having different problems now, you ought to perhaps post as a different question.